# TexStudio: Compile and Preview on File Save

Tags: texstudio, automation, preview, shortcut, live-preview

I've spent the better part of the last couple hours searching through StackExchange and Google to find either a WYSIWYG style LaTeX editor, and for Windows, I have settled with `TexStudio` as the best offline option (I'm used to using `Overleaf`.)

In any case, one thing that would be a HUGE quality-of-life improvement for me would be to compile and preview my file upon save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). Unfortunately, if I try to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> the shortcut to `Build` and `View`, it removes it as the hotkey to save.

Is there any way to set a hotkey for more than one command? Or any other way to automatically preview my document when I save?

I am using the built-in PDF viewer in `TeXStudio`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with TeXstudio default shortcuts?

Comment: Agreed with Aradnix. Furthermore, TeXstudio does save the file before Build&View, so it sort of does what you want anyway. F5 is even shorter than Ctrl+S.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is not really TeXstudio's but the user's, that is, you need to leave the WYSIWYG approach aside to be able to work with TeXstudio, at least in the traditional way. Fortunately TeXstudio supports synctex which is quite useful for both the come and go from code to PDF and vice versa. However, if you're not willing to take that step, you might as well use LyX.

Comment: *set a hotkey for more than one command* is the same as use `\label{}` twice to refer two different equations!!! Just use the hot key for Build&View as mentioned before.  Note that what will happen in Build&View you can configure in Options Menu.

Comment: @Winch FYI, you *can* use Overleaf offline. The app is open-source, so you can host (run) it on your computer and access it using a web browser, even if you aren't connected to the Internet (see the [installation instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide); even though it recommends using Toolbox, I prefer these instructions). **You don't even need LaTeX on your computer.** Some features are different, but most are the same. **The downside is that unlike TexStudio, it stores files in MongoDB, so you can't manipulate the file tree outside of Overleaf.**

Answer (score 11):

To add to gusbrs's answer. Because Ctrl+S is in my muscle memory, I chose to bind Build & View as Ctrl+S which works great for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use TeXstudio's default shortcut for "Build & View", which is <kbd>F5</kbd>. Once TeXstudio already saves the file before "Build & View" it does both things you are trying to achieve with a single keystroke.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the setting "Auto-recompile document on changes" in the configuration tab "Internal PDF Viewer" to update the internal preview after saving the file.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Zoraiyo, and welcome to the TeX Stack Exchange! While the method in your answer works, it doesn't seem to answer the intended question.

Comment: @Someone Why does it not answer the question?

Comment: The question asks how to compile on-demand. If the document is particularly large, auto-recompiling could become a problem. Also, there are multiple answers that already work.

Comment: @Someone The question asks "Or any other way to automatically preview my document when I save?"

Comment: The wording implies that the OP asked that as an alternative if the first method didn't work. Multiple answers show it does.

Comment: @Someone So now the author (and other users with the same problem) have multiple methods to choose what suits them best. What's wrong with that? If you personally think one of the other answer is more useful, upvote another answer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for adding the screenshot. I never thought that my answer to such an old question would directly cause so much attention. 
I also had the compile time problem in mind, but so far it has never been a problem for me (<100 pages).

Comment: @Zoraiyo You're welcome! I'm sure your answer will be helpful for some of the users who stumble across this question. I think the attention for your answer was just a concatenation of circumstances. As it was your first answer, it got automatically added to the "first answer"-review queue and due to the relatively concise text the system automatically added it to yet another review queue to check if a post is low quality or not.

Comment: Personally, I'm doing it the other way round and let texstudio automatically safe my file whenever I compile, but I never had problems with compile times either. And even if a document is so large that it would give trouble, there are easy way to speed things up, like the subfiles package.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Option+S as a new shortcut (if you are using MacOS).